# Try all thresholding in Skimage.Filter

Tags: python, scikit-image

I try to see all the different types of thresholding for an image.

```
skimage.__version__
0.10.1

from skimage.filter import try_all_threshold
Importerror: cannot import name try_all_threshold

import skimage.filter as sf
img=try_all_tgreshold (gray)
Attributeerror: 'module' object has no attribute try_all_threshold
```

dir (sf) gives all thresholding functions but it has not try all threshold function
how to use try all thresholding function in skimage.
Thanks

Comment: I think it is `from skimage.filters import try_all_threshold` - you are missing an `s`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using skimage version 0.13.1. Update skimage should solve the problem.

Did you try the example in the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_thresholding.html)?

```
from skimage.filters import try_all_threshold

img = data.page()

# Here, we specify a radius for local thresholding algorithms.
# If it is not specified, only global algorithms are called.
fig, ax = try_all_threshold(img, figsize=(10, 8), verbose=False)
plt.show()
```

This works for me.